# How I can get all last year's records of SQLite table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table in which each record has a date. I want to get records based on the last 365 days.

```
WHERE MYDATE < date('now', '-365 day') is not working
```

The table has the following:

```
George 10/4/2016 Pass
John   4/5/2015 Pass
John   19/7/2013  Fail
```

So I run the above and

I get John with 19/7/2013 and George with 10/4/2016

Comment: *is this correct?* obviously, no ... `julianday('365')` what it supposed to return? *based on the last 365 days.* Then why you are using "equal" sign ? you should check if `yourDateColmnAaDays` is greater then `nowAsDays minus 365`

Comment: `... WHERE strfttime('%Y', date) = " + year;`

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `date` column?

Comment: 4/5/2016 is the format

Comment: Wrong format. It should be `2016-04-05`.

Comment: Yes ok, but what about system locale, I shall transform the date before saving ? How I am going to tell sqlite this is your regional setting?

Comment: SQLite only accepts the ISO format. IF you want to display the date in your locale, just use a SimpleFormat. Same to make your local date in ISO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save dates in SQLite format

Answer (score 1):

SELECT
Name
FROM
Persons
WHERE
date <= date('now', '-365 days')

maybe do the job

Comment: With this I get all three records